# vim: Change display number

Tags: vim

How do I tell tell vim to use a non-default display number. The searches I've done so far just show me line numbers, which is not what I want.
The xserver crashed and restarted, so I'm not on the default display, but instead am on :2. I would have assumed it would be something like `:set display=:2`, but that is not the case.

[image: display error]

Answer (score 0):

Check that the terminal the vim was invoked from has the correct value in the `DISPLAY` environment variable and restart vim. Vim will use the display number from that variable.

I don't see a way of changing the display without restarting vim and will accept that over this current answer.